# Click to new window.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

im learning wpf for the first time,

i have made this far

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
    }
```

lets say its my click button 'home' some how i have made a new window store.xaml at the same product.

**how can i connect them ?**

heres a sc

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems a bit vague to me, if you simply want to display the store inside the same window you should not implement the content of the window directly but only use the window as a shell for your content, if your store is a window as well you should refactor it into a UserControl which then can be added to the window.

You can also use Pages, see the [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) for more info on that.